# VueJS Import only used styles from bootstrap

Tags: css, vue.js, import, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using npm bootstrap and importing only the classes I used for my project in custom.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables.scss';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/transitions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/nav.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/navbar.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/buttons.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/forms.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/images.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/type.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/media.scss';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot.scss";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/spacing.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/text.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/background.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/position.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/sizing.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/spacing.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/borders.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/float.scss";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/transition.scss";
```

however the navbar-collapse don't work anymore. what is the missing file that I need to import? any help would be appreciated

Edit:
Added all bootstrap and still doesnt work

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited

Bootstrap JS folder is located in the directory like this. You will use @import statement to use it on your scss file.

```
bootstrap/
└── dist/
    ├── scss/
    └── js/
        ├── bootstrap.bundle.js
        ├── bootstrap.bundle.js.map
        ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js
        ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
        ├── bootstrap.js
        ├── bootstrap.js.map
        ├── bootstrap.min.js
        └── bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Also, make sure you install jQuery and Popper too as these are peer dependencies.

```
npm install --save jquery popper.js.
```

Comment: im using the cdn jquery on index.html but i'll try your suggestion thank you

Comment: it turns out I accidentally deleted the CDN for the bootstrap.min.js .. is there a way to import the bootstrap.min.js using npm so that i dont use any cdn in my index.html?

Comment: When you installed bootstrap, I am pretty sure there is also a js folder installed. If you find those, you will use @import statement to use it.

I will edit my answer so that you can see where the js directory should be located.